# ASP.net Identity claims value can not be set

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have a question about ASP.net Identity.
First, I want my system user has different properties. For example, Teacher have Name, Adress,PhoneNumber but Student just have Name and Score.Student and Teacher are both my system user.

So, I found a similar question in the bellow adress:
[How to create different user types in ASP.NET Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664434/how-to-create-different-user-types-in-asp-net-identity)

"If you need to store information that's unique to being a buyer or a seller, then you can also use claims, which are far more flexible than adding additional properties to your user model and definitely far more flexible that creating actual foreign key relationships to store extra data."——by above anwser.

So I learn about claims in ASP.Net Identity.But I find that the class Claim has the Value is read only, in other words, if i create a claim, and put Adress property in it ,I can't modify its value.
If the idea of using claim is not a good idea, what kind of method should i take?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this post. It shows a method to update a claim.

[How to update a claim in ASP.NET Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587414/how-to-update-a-claim-in-asp-net-identity)